# How to reset path vars after each batch call?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I'm performing a mass build (1000+) projects.  I call a batch file that calls another batch file that contains a long list of calls to project builds.  The problems is, after a few projects, the process stops and says "The input line is too long".  I did some research and found that the path environment vars are probably changing and therefore becoming too long.  How can I reset the path variable between each of the build calls?  Or is there another way I can solve this problem?

Comment: I will try that. May take a while to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is that in the batch file which modifies **PATH** or in one of the parent batch files you insert the line

```
set InitialPath=%PATH%
```

And later when the project is built another a line is inserted

```
PATH=%InitialPath%
```

A small batch file demonstrating this simple solution:

```
@echo off
rem Remember initial value of environment variable PATH.
set InitialPath=%PATH%
rem Environment variable PATH is modified to include a compiler directory.
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompiler\bin;%PATH%
rem Do here whatever must be done with modified PATH.
echo %PATH%
rem Restore the initial value of environment variable PATH.
PATH=%InitialPath%
echo %PATH%
rem Optionally the environment variable InitialPath is removed finally.
set InitialPath=
```